# Difference between Microsoft Hosted Agents and Self-hosted agents and their applicability

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm new to Azure pipelines and curious to know the exact difference between Microsoft Hosted agents and Self-Hosted Agents. Also need to know in what scenarios we should use either of the agents. Do these agents have relation with On-prem and cloud deployments?

Comment: This is most likely just answered by reviewing the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Microsoft-hosted agents :**

With Microsoft-hosted agents, maintenance and upgrades are taken care of for you. **Each time** you run a pipeline, you get a **fresh** virtual machine. The virtual machine is discarded after one use. Microsoft-hosted agents can run jobs directly on the VM or in a container.

The pre-defined `Azure Pipelines` agent pool offers several virtual machine images to choose from, each including a broad range of tools and software. You can see the installed software for each hosted agent by choosing the `Included Software` link in the [table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software).

Microsoft-hosted agents run on secure Azure platform. However, you must be aware of the following security considerations.

- Although Microsoft-hosted agents run on Azure public network, they
  are **not assigned** public IP addresses. So, external entities cannot
  target Microsoft-hosted agents.
- Microsoft-hosted agents are run in individual VMs, which are
  re-imaged after each run. Each agent is dedicated to a single
  organization, and each VM hosts only a single agent.
- There are several benefits to running your pipeline on
  Microsoft-hosted agents, from a security perspective. If you run
  untrusted code in your pipeline, such as contributions from forks, it
  is safer to run the pipeline on Microsoft-hosted agents than on
  self-hosted agents that reside in your corporate network.
- When a pipeline needs to access your corporate resources behind a
  firewall, you have to **whitelist** the IP address range for the Azure
  geography. This may increase your exposure as the range of IP
  addresses is rather large and since machines in this range can belong
  to other customers as well. The best way to prevent this is to avoid
  the need to access internal resources.
- Hosted images do not conform to [CIS hardening benchmarks](https://www.cisecurity.org/benchmark/azure/). To use
  CIS-hardened images, you must create either self-hosted agents or
  scale-set agents.

For **capabilities**, **limitations** and other details about hosted agent ,please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#capabilities-and-limitations).

For many teams this is the simplest way to run your jobs. You can try it first and see if it works for your build or deployment. If not, you can use a self-hosted agent.

**Self-hosted agents :**

Self-hosted agents give you more control to install dependent software needed for your builds and deployments. Also, machine-level caches and configuration persist from run to run, which can **boost speed**.

You can install the agent on Linux, macOS, Windows machines or Docker container.

The performance advantages of private agent:

- If you use a self-hosted agent, you can run incremental builds. For
  example, if you define a pipeline that does not clean the repo and
  does not perform a clean build, your builds will typically run
  faster. When you use a Microsoft-hosted agent, you don't get these
  benefits because the agent is destroyed after the build or release
  pipeline is completed.
- A Microsoft-hosted agent can take longer to start your build. While
  it often takes just a few seconds for your job to be assigned to a
  Microsoft-hosted agent, it can sometimes take several minutes for an
  agent to be allocated depending on the load on our system.

**Summary**: There are many differences between hosted agent and self-hosted agent, you can choose the appropriate agent according to your needs. For details,please refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) .